# DropDownList postback issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, autopostback

I have a DropDownList inside a usercontrol, which is itself inside a usercontrol.

The problem I have is that when someone selects an item from the DDL, I need to fire a postback so I can update some textbox's on the inner usercontrol.

But if I use autopostback, I get a JS error "Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus."

Anyone have any ideas on this? Driving me loopy...

```
       <asp:MultiView ID="mvInvoiceItem" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="vwInvoiceItemList" runat="server">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_AddInvoiceItem" runat="server" 
                onclick="btn_AddInvoiceItem_Click">Add Part</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvwInvoiceItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                EnableModelValidation="True" 
                OnRowCommand="gvwInvoiceItems_RowCommand"
                DataKeyNames="Id" 
                AllowPaging="True" Width="750px" PageSize="3" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="1" itemstyle-cssclass="invisibleColumn" >
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="invisibleColumn" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="invisibleColumn" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IsSupplied" HeaderText="IsSupplied" SortExpression="IsSupplied" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="Cost" />
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/btn_select.png" CommandName="SelectRow" Text="Select" />
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/btn_remove.png" CommandName="RemoveRow" Text="Remove" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vwInvoiceItemEdit" runat="server">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InvoiceItem" runat="server" 
                            Text="Part.."></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_InvoiceItem" runat="server" 
                            DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" Width="215px" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="dd_InvoiceItem_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InvoiceItemQuantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity.."></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="250px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_InvoiceItemQuantity" runat="server" MaxLength="100" 
                            Width="190px" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InvoiceItemPrice" runat="server" Text="Price.."></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="250px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_InvoiceItemPrice" runat="server" MaxLength="100" 
                            Width="190px" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InvoiceItemIsSupplied" runat="server" Text="Supplied.."></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_InvoiceItemIsSupplied" runat="server"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_InvoiceItemCost" runat="server" Text="Cost.."></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="250px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_InvoiceItemCost" runat="server" MaxLength="100" 
                            Width="190px" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_InvoiceItemSave" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/btn_save.png" onclick="btn_InvoiceItemSave_Click" />
                        &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_InvoiceItemCancel" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/btn_cancel.png" onclick="btn_InvoiceItemCancel_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
```

There is nothing in the Page_Load for the inner usercontrol, it is initialised from the outside with calls to set the InvoiceId and PopulateGrid.

Comment: That is a javascript error message and not ASP.NET. Are you trying to set the focus to a control manually with a js-function? If so, you need to check if it can get focus: `if( element.type != "hidden" && element.style.display != "none"  && !element.disabled ) { element.focus(); }`

Comment: Can you post more code?  It sounds like you are calling .Focus() on a control that isn't visible.

Comment: Tim - I'm not trying to set the focus.

Comment: OkayGuy - I've tried using an UpdatePanel

Comment: Peter - updated with the markup

Comment: Chris can you use [at] to let people know you reply to them like this @TimSchmelter .

Comment: @OkayGuy sorry, newbie mistake!

Comment: No problem Mr.Buthcer, I am just trying to help so you can communicate easily to find solutions to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite odd. Upon further investigation I found that someone had implemented this solution to a focus issue http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/restoring-lost-focus-in-update-panel.html

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Resources/Focus.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

The solution to my problem was removing the reference to this JS from the ScriptManager on the hosting ASPX page.